# PHP array data loading problems?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database, xampp

Hi guys I try developed some web application to analyze stock market as part of my college project.

Necessary data is collected from yahoo and stored in my db. Table simply looks like 
nflx = table name - open,close,min,max are the names of the columns all declared as floats

I'm trying to use Trader- php extension 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.trader.php

The problem occur when I'm passing array OF my DB DATA for example($close) into trader function which in my scenario is trader_rsi
http://php.net/manual/en/function.trader-rsi.php

Error what im getting is simple  page connection error "this webpage is not available" err_connection_resset. Otherwise when I use array of data manually created by me ($real) and array is passed in to function trader_rsi everything work perfectly page is loaded and function returns rsi values.
Also I printed out both arrays ($real, $close) output format looks the same.

echo of `$real`:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 44.34 
    [1] => 44.09 
    [2] => 44.15 
    [3] => 43.61 
    [4] => 44.33 
    [5] => 44.83 
    [6] => 45.1
)
```

echo of `$close`:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 123.71 
    [1] => 126.45 
    [2] => 123.52 
    [3] => 123.03 
    [4] => 122.74 
    [5] => 120.51 
    [6] => 123.73 
)
```

Below is my code if someone have any idea what is wrong I would be appreciated.

```
<?php

require_once 'db.php';
require_once 'error.php';
    //connection to db
// Step 1
if (!($conn = mysql_connect($config['server'], $config['user'], $config['password'])))
{
//  showError();
}

// Step 2
if (!(mysql_select_db($config['database'], $conn)))
{
    //showError();

}


 // Sql queries 
 $get_db = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM nflx');
 //$alt_db = mysql_query ('ALTER TABLE nflx ADD rsi float');
 //$In_db = mysql_query ('INSERT INTO nflx (rsi) VALUES('$rsi')');


if (!$get_db) {
echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
}

if (mysql_num_rows($get_db) == 0) {
echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
exit;
}

// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop


 // array declaration
 $close = array();
  //$high = array();
// $low = array();
//$open = array();



while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($get_db)) {
$close[] = $row['close'];
//$high[] = $row['high'];
//$low[] = $row['low'];
//$open[] = $row['open'];

}

//print_r($close);


 //echo $close;  
 //Calculation of technical indicator
$timePeriod = 14;
 // $real =array (44.34,44.09,44.15,43.61,44.33,44.83,45.10,45.42,45.84,46.08,45.89,46.03,45.61,46.28,46.28,46.00,46.03,46.41,46.22,45.64,46.21,46.25,45.71,46.45,45.78,45.35,44.03,44.18,44.22,44.57,43.42,42.66,43.13);
// PROBLEM OCCUR IN LINE BELOW WHEN ARRAY OF DB DATA IS PASSED IN
$rsi = trader_rsi($close , $timePeriod);
print_r($rsi);
//print_r($real);


 mysql_free_result($get_db);


mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

I forgot mention Im using latest xampp and php 5.6 on win 8

Comment: Does your script take more than 30 seconds to process?

Comment: Its like 5-6 second when trying to connect to locoalhost then try reconnect and finally comes up wit nothing. But as i mention above this occur only in one scenario. In all other cases I dont have problem runs any my scripts on xampp ..

Comment: I was asking about that because it seems that your script takes too much time to be executed, so when it reach the time limit it just cut the connection. How big is your `$close` array?

Comment: Is only a testing data so its around 40 records in table. I can't even process that.

Comment: Finally solved this by redefining array as a float, I had column 'close' in my Db as float but array must be define also as float otherwise function wont work.      $close[] = ((float)$row['close']);

Comment: Probably it was casted by mysql_fetch_aasoc to string..?Any way this is solution     $close[] = ((float)$row['close']); .    Uby Thanks for trying to help me!!